# how to use @ in python.. and the @property and the @classmethod

Tags: python

this is my code:

```
def a():
    print 'sss'

@a()
def b():
    print 'aaa'

b()
```

and the Traceback  is:

```
sss
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\zjm_code\a.py", line 8, in <module>
    @a()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

so how to use the '@'

thanks

**updated**

```
class a:
    @property
    def b(x):
        print 'sss'

aa=a()
print aa.b
```

it print :

```
sss
None
```

how to use @property

thanks

**updated2**

and the classmethod:

```
class a:
    @classmethod
    def b(x):
        print 'sss'

aa=a()
print aa.b
```

the it print :

```
<bound method classobj.b of <class __main__.a at 0x00B2DC00>>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A decorator needs to be a callable object (either a function or an object implementing __call__), where the parameter is the function that has been decorated, and the result is a function that will replace the function that has been decorated, so, to use your example of printing 'sss' instead of printing 'aaa':

```
>>> def a(f):
...     def replacementfunc():
...         print 'sss'
...     return replacementfunc;
... 
>>> @a
... def b():
...     print 'aaa'
... 
>>> b()
sss
```

Or, a more elaborate example:

```
>>> class print_decorator(object):
...     def __init__(self,text):
...        self.text = text;
...     def __call__(self,f):
...        def replacement():
...            print self.text;
...        return replacement;
... 
>>> @print_decorator("Hello world!")
... def b():
...     print 'aaa';
... 
>>> b()
Hello world!
```

**Edit**
As for your updated question, you need to look at the documentation for [@property](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property). It's not clear exactly what you are trying to accomplish, although my guess is that you want:

```
class a:
    @property
    def b(self):
        return 'sss'

aa=a()
print aa.b # prints 'sss', whereas without @property, prints <function ... >
```

Comment: I may be wrong in this context..but this is what I think...a decorator should not be replacing the function totally..it should be decorating it..i.e say ***aaa*** (*** at the front & back is printed using a decorator)

Comment: @SysAdmin, a decorator can do that by returning a function that calls the function that has been passed-in; however, the actual semantics is that the returned function takes over the name of the function. The use of @x def f(): .... is the same as def f(): ... followed by f = x(f);

Answer (score 4):

The line `@a()` means "`a` is a callable, returning some other callable, which can be called with a function as its only argument and will return a callable".  If you're not familiar with the term `callable`, it's just a generalization of `function`: it can be a function, a class, or an instance of a class that has a `__call__` method.

Your `def a` is returning `None`, so you're clearly violating the "decorator contract" that you're requesting with the `@a()` syntax.

If you just used `@a`, without the `()`, then `a` would have to accept the function as its argument and return a callable.

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but if it's just "print something in a decorator for a function, then this would work:

```
def a():
    print 'sss'
    return lambda f: f
```

*Now* you can use `@a()` and live happily ever after, since **this** version does respect the "decorator contract" I explained in the first paragraph.

Comment: @zjm, be sensible: one question per question!  Anyway, the property returns what the `def b()` returns, and that's `None` since you just fall off the end, and _of course_ printing the classmethod (without calling) shows you that it's a method bound to the class, **what else** could it possibly be showing?!